# How do I put text that is inside a P element next to a image?

Tags: css, html

Here is my code:

```
<img id="mepic" src="images/example.jpg"  width="70px" height"60px">
<p>This is some example text that i want next to the image on the right hand side</p>
```

At the moment, the text is underneath the image. How do I put the text next to the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO CSS & JavaScript, PURE HTML**

```
<p><img src="image.png" alt="image"/>&nbsp;Text beside image</p>
```

Place `<img>` inside a `<p>` can put the image surround by text. Read [more here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_align.asp).

NOTE: `<img>` tag has `display: inline` by default and `&nbsp;` is basic a non-breaking space, read [more here](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/nbsp.html).

```html
<p>This is some text.&nbsp;
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Smiley face">&nbsp;This is some text.</p><br/>
<p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Smiley face" align="middle">&nbsp;This text is next to the image</p>
```

Comment: Hey, Just to remind users: align is Not supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it without changing the `html` structure

As `img` is a `inline` element you can set the next sibling `p` to `inline`

By default `p` is a `block` element so it is taking full `width`

more about [+ selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

```css
img + p {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: top; /* so that p aligns to the top of img*/
}
```

```html
<img id="mepic" src="http://placehold.it/70x60" width="70" height="60">
<p>This is some example text that i want next to the image on the right hand side</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place text to right side of an image, here's code which will allow it:

```
   <p><img src="example.jpg" alt="img"> Image text here.</p>
```

Running example: https://jsfiddle.net/apc5spcu/

**Alternately**, you could use divs and make a nicer looking image form.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="imgdiv">
        <img src="example.jpg" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="textdiv">
        <p> Image text here.</p>
        <p> Image text here.</p>
        <p> Image text here.</p>
        <p> Image text here.</p>
    </div>
```

This code makes use of 'Float' which positions each division next to eachother on left and right sides.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:540px;
}
.imgdiv {
    float:left;
    width:140px;
}
.textdiv {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
}
```

Running example: https://jsfiddle.net/apc5spcu/1/

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, since you tagged this as HTML5, you would be better off using `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` to mark up this content.

For example:

```
<figure>
   <img id="mepic" src="images/example.jpg" alt="Text" />
   <figcaption>This is some example text that i want next to the image on the right hand side</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Then you could style it like:

```
figure {
   margin: 0;
   width: 600px;
   height: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}
figure img {
   width: 30%;
   float: left;
}
figure figcaption {
   width: 70%;
   float: right;
}
```